# Within AWS and AWS to On-Premise private connectivity

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have done a clean sweep of AWS docs but couldn't find answer to my scenario. I'm looking for a solution wherein I will have **private connectivity(no data flows through Internet but within AWS network)** between my two VPCs and VPC to On-premise connectivity. I'm aware of `AWS PrivateLink` and `Direct Connect` but they have some limitations e.g. a RDS Instance cannot be exposed as an Endpoint service to be consumed and things like that.

Is there any way I can achieve the above ?

Comment: RDS cannot be exposed as Endpoint simply because it lives directly within your VPC so why would you need additional Endpoint when you already have one? Please, be more specific about what you are trying to achieve and what is not working for you. `PrivateLink`, `DirectConnect` and `VPNs` can ensure almost full private communication. In some special cases, you will need to install some proxy but that is about it.

Comment: @jagatjyoti Are you wanting to establish a VPN connection across your existing Internet connection, or are you wanting to rent a fibre connection (Direct Connect) from your Telco to connect to AWS?

Comment: John-  I'm trying with our office network which is existing Internet connection. 
@MatusDubrava I wanted a private communication between an EC2 in VPC A to RDS Instance in VPC B using PrivateLink which is not supported in PrivateLink. You can only expose an endpoint service with NLB on top and then backend target groups. Which other service can suffice this use case ?

Answer (score 0):

AWS Transit Gateway allows you to setup direct networking between VPCs and your on premises environment.  It supports both VPN and Direct Connect for the on premises leg of the connection.

https://aws.amazon.com/transit-gateway/